# .svg Files Made In Inkscape Won't Import Correctly Into Blender

Tags: svg

I saved an SVG in Inkscape that had only text on it. When I import it into Blender, it will only create a collection, but no curves. I noticed something odd. I converted that SVG into a PNG. Then, I converted the PNG to an SVG using Inkscape's trace bitmap feature. After that, Blender recognized the SVG just fine. I can't tell if it's a Blender problem or an Inkscape problem.

Comment: "*I converted that SVG into a PNG. Then, I converted the PNG to an SVG using Inkscape's trace bitmap feature.*" That's a very roundabout way to get a path from text and will ensure serious loss of quality. Why not convert (a copy of) the text to path directly, instead of making an image and then converting back to vector?

Comment: I was just experimenting and found out that way.